# How to use Assert/Type with null allowed in Symfony?

Tags: symfony, validation, assert

Is it possible to validate the entity's property with exact type OR null? 
In other words, the property can have **optinal** value of exact type.

For example, property $date can be set (`\Datetime` type) or not :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
 * @Assert\Type("\DateTime")
 */
protected $date;
```

Do not mind `nullable=true` in `@ORM\Column` section, it only applies to DB-level, not model validation.

**The problem is**: If $date not present, the error is:

`Expected argument of type "DateTime", "NULL" given`

Comment: How about something like `function setDate(\DateTime $date = null) {`?

Comment: Also what happens when you add [`IsNull`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/IsNull.html) or [`Blank`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Blank.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with `@Assert\DateTime()` instead:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
 * @Assert\DateTime()
 */
protected $date;
```

`Type` forces field to be instance of specified type, while other constraints validates value if it's not null (except for `NotNull` etc).

Remember that `@Assert\DateTime()` also accepts correct datetime **string**. But you can handle it with proper setter to force this value to be either null or `\DateTime`.